# Convergence of a sequence to an arbitrary set

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have that a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$, $\{y_{n}\}$, is such that, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $y_{n}\in B_{\frac{1}{n}}(A)$, where $A$ is some arbitrary non-empty set.

Must it be the case that $\{y_{n}\}$ is converging to some point in $A$? I think that this must be the case. The reason is as follows.

Suppose $y_{n}\rightarrow b$, where $b$ is not in $A$. But, given the above, we know that there is a small enough open ball around $b$, such that it only contains finitely many $y_{n}$. Thus, $y_{n}$ cannot converge to a point outside $A$.

Thank you.

Comment: The sequence may not converge at all. It is also relevant if $A$ is *closed* or not.

Comment: What does $B_{\frac{1}{n}}(A)$ mean? Usually, a ball is centred around a point. What does it mean for a ball to be centred around a set?

Answer (score 0):

let $A=[0,1], y_n=\frac  1n$ for $n$ even and $y_n=1+\frac  1n$ for  $n$ odd. Then $y_n \in B_{\frac 1n} (A)$ and $(y_n)$ is not convergent.

If $A=(0,1), y_n=\frac  1n$ for all $n$ then $y_n \in B_{\frac 1n} (A)$ and $(y_n)$  converges to $0$ which does not belong to  $A$.

If you assume that $(y_n)$ is a  convergent sequence and that $A$ is closed then we can say  that the limit of $(y_n)$ belongs to $A$.